# FOS user update password not working in rare case

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony2 CRUD generator to manage users . Very rare incident is happening when I update password of user it does not updated in the database. But when I update user password with any other fields such as name or email then password is updated.

My UserType Form class is below

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('plainPassword','password')
        ->add('roles','choice',array('choices'=>array('ROLE_ADMIN'=>'Admin','ROLE_MEMBER'=>'Member') ,'multiple'  => true,'expanded'=>true))
        ->add('path','hidden')
        ->add('file');
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Ars\PlaybookBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'ars_playbookbundle_user';
}
}
```

My crud controller update action look like

```
/**
 * Edits an existing User entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="user_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("ArsPlaybookBundle:User:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ArsPlaybookBundle:User')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);


   $email=$request->request->all();
   $password   =     $email['ars_playbookbundle_user']['plainPassword'];


   if(isset($password)){
      $editForm->get('plainPassword')->setData($password); 
   }



    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    //\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($editForm->getData()); die;
    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        $entity->upload();
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice', 'Your changes were saved!'
        );
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working by using user manager instead of form or entityManager. Now I can update only password field without changing any other field.